# Return a string using HQL

Tags: java

*

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT c.name FROM CompanyEntity c WHERE c.id = :companyId");
query.setInteger("companyId", companyId);
result = query.toString();
```

Hi.I am fetching name which is String from query. But the result is not returned properly.I am getting the query as a result.Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If your query returns a single value (and it probably does), you can use query.uniqueResult()

Comment: @dsp_user thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Query` object capsulates the formulated query itself, *not* the result of the query. In order to execute the query and retrieve the result, you have to call

```
query.list();
```

which returns a List of the selected properties (i.e. `name`in this case).

If your query returns a single result, there is a convenience method:

```
query.uniqueResult();
```

And if your query is an update statement, you can execute it without having any result:

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

(this last one returns the number of updated entities).